# BeautifulSoup4 can't go deep enough to find articles

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I just started experimenting with python and BeautifulSoup.

I want to get the links to articles that are related to a specific city

Here is the current code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

city = "london"
result = requests.get('https://www.origo.hu/kereses/index.html?q=' + city)


def main_loop():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, features="lxml")
    articles = soup.find("div", "oc-articleList")

    print(articles)


if result.status_code == 200:
    main_loop()
else:
    print('error:', result.status_code)
```

The result is:

```
<div class="oc-articleList"></div>
```

The first thing I tried was getting the articles with:

```
articles = soup.find_all("article")
```

But it could find anything.

If you check the sites source code it looks something like this:

```
<div class="oc-articleList">
    <article>...</article>
    <article>...</article>
    <article>...</article>
    <article>...</article>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

How can I make BS parse deeper into the DOM?

Comment: Without the actual url it might be hard to get an answer.

Comment: Can you share URL?

Comment: I edited it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER 1)
TLDR: Just add another .find() OR .find_all() after searching for the first element to find nested elements.

Once you found the div element with *soup.find()* (in your case variable articles), you can just call another query on it with *.find()* or *.find_all()*.

To illustrate, based on the code you provided:

```
...

def main_loop():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, features="lxml")

    ### ADDED .find_all() after the first search ###
    articles = soup.find("div", "oc-articleList").find_all("article")

    print(articles)


...
```

Keeping in mind that *find_all()* will return a list now

ANSWER 2)

Requests only captured HTML and CSS content while JavaScript did not display.

Solution: use pre-render service i.e

```
result = requests.get("http://service.prerender.io/https://www.sample.com/")
```

Comment: I tired this but it just returns an empty array.

Comment: Second answer added